# Android app to ask me questions randomly during the day

Tags: android, health

I'm quite interested in the [Quantified Self](http://www.quantifiedself.com) movement and general self improvement and I would like an application to help with this.

Here's a few use cases I would like:

- Randomly during the day ask me a random question:

  - How happy are you (out of 10)?
  - Are you engaged with your work?
  - What are you doing right now?
  - Are you in bed right now?

(I'd like to be able to set the questions/answer possibilities, as well as the time frames of the day that the questions can be asked).

- Trigger asking a question at a specific time in the future.

Sometimes I get depressed and might start playing computer games. What I would like the app to do is, if I recognize that I might be in a risky frame of mind, trigger a button on the application, which will then ask me a question, in say 6 hours, to ask specific questions.

The answers for all these should be logged, and then so I can then later extract trends, data etc.

Comment: See this thread:https://www.reddit.com/r/QuantifiedSelf/comments/sezg00/anyone_know_of_an_app_for_android_that_can_ask_me/ which links to this wiki: https://wiki.openhumans.org/wiki/Tools_to_survey_symptoms_and_states

Answer (score 1):

- [MoodPanda](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.MoodPanda) is mostly about your first point, and has a large support community.

  > "Analyse your mood on graphs and calendars; get support and advice from the MoodPanda community".
- [Daylio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.daylio) - Describes itself as a "Diary, Journal, Mood Tracker".

  > "Pick your mood and add activities you have been doing during the day. You can also add notes and keep an old school diary. Daylio is collecting recorded moods and activities in the statistics and calendar. This format will help you to understand your habits better. Keep track of your activities and create patterns to become more productive!".
- [Universum](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.schustovd.diary) - Diary, Journal, Notes

  > "Do you want to keep a diary of your own thoughts and feelings or finances or brilliant ideas or maybe a story of a trip in photos? Or maybe all at once? All this can be done using the universal diary. Keep track of your daily mood and routines. It will help you discover causes of your ups and downs".
- [Journey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.journey.app): Diary, Journal

  > "Write journal notes. Add mood entry. Explore interesting statistics about your moods and activities on monthly or yearly charts. View throwback entries. Set reminders".

Interestingly [Quantified Self has a fairly lengthy list of Android APPs](http://quantifiedself.com/guide/tag/lifelogging) .

Comment: Moodpanda only seems to ask you a preset question about mood as does daylio. Universum can record arbitrary things but doesn't poll you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [time channel with the e-mail channel on IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/recipes/13865-mypermissions-monthly-reminder) to automate e-mailing you at a given time. Replies to the e-mail will be logged and you can look through your e-mail inbox for sent e-mails to the ifttt e-mail address.

Answer (score 0):

[Trackthisforme](https://www.trackthisfor.me/): to track just about anything you want, doesn't do custom questions I think. you can set a mood tracker.

[Diary - mood tracker](http://daylio.webflow.io/): specifically to track your mood, can ask you what you have been upto where you can make a note and select activities you are doing and the mood you are feeling from awful to awesome. Also can provide charts to give stats.

[Pacifica - Stress & Anxiety](https://www.thinkpacifica.com/): Stress, Anxiety, depression relief based on mindful meditation, also has mood logging but it's more about the self help aspects.

Comment: Track this for me is dead

Answer (score -1):

It takes some settings up, but IIRC this app should do everything you are looking for via notifications: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jayvant.liferpgmissions

Comment: Please include screenshots showing each of the bullet points of the question, thanks!

Comment: Please also read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality . When fixed your answer could be a great answer :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul ahh that's fair, thanks for the feedback. unfortunately I decided ages ago that this app wasn't for me and uninstalled, so screen shots are not possible. however it probably is a good fit for the questioner should they decide to take a look. It can indeed offer periodic time-based prompts and record and track the responses to those prompts.