# Software for tracking/tweaking medication efficacy

Tags: android, health

I was recently diagnosed with ADHD, and part of the treatment, is treatment with medication. There are a wide range of stimulants commonly used, and their dosage varies person to person.

As far as I understand, the right dosage and medication is a balance between controlling ADHD symptoms, and producing unwanted side effects (such as insomnia, irritability).

The problem I'm having, is 'How do I know if the medication is working?'. It's kind of hard to measure this stuff from a subjective, retrospective viewpoint in a doctor's appointment once a month.

What might be effective is an app that regularly polls you for a response to the severity of ADHD symptoms and medication side effects.

I did ask this question here, but it got no response:

[Android app to ask me questions randomly during the day](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18389/android-app-to-ask-me-questions-randomly-during-the-day)

Are there any softwares specifically designed for monitoring ADHD or mood disorders?

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, It is hard to find something out there that is specifically for tracking ADHD med side effects.

Mood tracking apps may have some of the features you are looking for. [Here's a list of popular ones](http://psyberguide.org/expert_opinion/apps-for-bi-polar-disorder-expert-review/)

A website like [Iodine.com](http://www.iodine.com/), that collects user feedback on meds and has a community crowdsourcing element around popular meds, may also be helpful if you are looking for a baseline or better understanding of what to expect.