# Offline personal survey app

Tags: android

I would like to monitor my mood over time. Basically, I want an app that lets me create a questionnaire that I can take as many times as I want during a day and export the results.

As inputs, I expect to be able to select:

- Sliding bar
- Radio buttons or Drop-downs
- Free form text box

I expect to be able to export the data to a text file for later analysis.

There are tons of offline survey creators available, however is there a simple one that completes these basic tasks? I'm fine with paying for it.

## Related Apps

- [T2 Mood Tracker](http://t2health.dcoe.mil/apps/t2-mood-tracker): Allows for sliding-only inputs. Although data export is possible, it's unclear on how to read the binary export file.
- [Track Your Happiness](https://www.trackyourhappiness.org/): Doesn't allow for customized questions.

## Related Questions

There is a related question "[Android app to ask me questions randomly during the day](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/18389/2134)", however the difference is:

- I don't need random interval notifications, since I will use [Randomly RemindMe](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jamesmorrisstudios.com.randremind&hl=en) for that purpose.
- I want a fixed set of questions I can answer, not a question selected randomly from a set.

There is also a related question on Psychology & Neuroscience StackExchange "[Longitudinal mobile mood tracking app with random reminders](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/longitudinal-mobile-mood-tracking-app-with-random-reminders)", but the requirements are more loose and there are no conclusive answers yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the psychology community, this type of mobile application is called ["experience sampling" or "ecological momentary assessments"](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5143469/).

Most applications are very expensive, however there's recently been an open-source solution released called [Experience Sampler](http://experiencesampler.com/), which lets you create your own survey apps for both Android and iPhone using Cordova.